# Meaning of chief curiosity

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Does anyone know what the chief curiosity means?

I am reading a [review](https://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/the-emperors-club-2002) based on a movie called [the emperor’s club.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_Club) The sentence is:

> The **chief curiosity** of the film is how it seems to present one view of the teacher, but cannot prevent itself from revealing another.

Definition of chief on [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chief):

> **1 :** accorded highest rank or office
>
> - *chief* librarian
> - the company's *chief* executive
>
> **2 :** of greatest importance or influence
>
> - the *chief* reasons
> - their *chief** accomplishment

Definition of curiosity on [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curiosity):

> **1 :** desire to know

If I add them together, they don’t make sense.

Does anyone know what it means? Also, any synonyms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there with your research skills, you just need to read a bit further down the definition for curiosity:

> **3 a :** one that arouses interest especially for uncommon or exotic characteristics
>
> - Tobacco was once regarded as a *curiosity* in Europe.
>
> **b :** an unusual knickknack : curio
>
> - The antique shop was full of *curiosities*.
>
> **c :** a curious trait or aspect

Combining definition **3c** for "curiosity" with your previously quoted definition **2** for "chief" gives:

> The **curious aspect of greatest importance** of the film is how it seems to present one view of the teacher, but cannot prevent itself from revealing another.

Answer (score 1):

When people have [*curiosity*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/curiosity?s=t) about something, they are intrigued and want to know more.

When a thing, in part or whole, is a *curiosity*, it has some quality or feature people find unusual or intriguing, i.e., something which arouses their curiosity.

The author of the review finds the multiple points of view in the film its most intriguing feature, its chief (i.e., main) curiosity. There's nothing to suggest that's the main point of the film.